# i am sending from asp.net with out any errors...but the html template is not viewing in mail..it showing download option only

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

Actually the mail(html template) is sending from asp.net with out any errors...but the html template is not viewing in mail..it showing download option only..

code is ..

```
string strMailContent = "Welcome new user";

string cid = "banner.jpg";
string path = Server.MapPath(@"images/banner.jpg"); // my logo is placed in images folder
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
MailAddressCollection addcoll = new MailAddressCollection();
addcoll.Add("kollihari1209@gmail.com");
addcoll.Add("kollihari1209@gmail.com");
mailMessage.From = addcoll[0];
mailMessage.To.Add(addcoll[1]);
mailMessage.Subject = "Welcome new User";
LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(path);
logo.ContentId = "banner";

AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body><img src=cid:companylogo/>     <br></body></html>" + strMailContent, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
av1.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(av1);
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient mailSender = new SmtpClient(); 
mailSender.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
mailSender.Port = 587;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added your text after the end of the html `body` tag. It needs to be inside of the body.